# How do usual arithmetic conversions work?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I was running this code in VS2019:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string mystring = "hello world";
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if (mystring[j + 1] == 'w') {
            cout<<"string contains w letter\n";
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And I realized that when I run it on Debug mode on an x86 platform, everything is ok, but if I change the platform to x64, the following warning appears:

> C26451    Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4-byte value and then casting the result to an 8-byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2).

It seems to be related to [Usual arithmetic conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26451), such that, if the operands are of different types, a conversion is applied to one of them before calculation. But if they are equal, that still happens?

If I print `typeid(j).name()` and `typeid(1).name()`, it prints `int` for both, so what is the reason for this warning? The warning is fixed if I change the `if` condition to `(mystring[j + static_cast<__int64>(1)] == 'w')`. The explanation, I think, should be that the number '1' is not considered of type `int` on x64, or it is but occupies different bits of memory than the `int` type on x64.

I would really like to clarify the issue, thanks.

Comment: The indexing type is `std::size_t` not `int` as you assume, and that's an `unsigned` type.

Comment: Please copy-paste the *actual* code leading to the warning, as a proper [mcve]. The code you show will have other unrelated errors.

Comment: As for the warning itself, once I fixed the errors I [can't replicate it](https://godbolt.org/z/PMf1vY1bd). Again, please copy-paste an actual [mcve] into the question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  Done, sorry for that.

Comment: Wow; the warning says that there's a problem with **casting**? You'd think a compiler writer would know better. There are no casts in this code. There is a **conversion**, which seems to be what the warning is about. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Comment: @ch -- that's the **second** use of "cast" in the warning. The first is is the one that's wrong.

Comment: @Pete You should file bug about the text being incorrect on the [VS Feedback](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/62/index.html) site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "C26451" warning is not a standard compiler warning. It's part of the C++ Code Guidelines Checker which is giving you 'recommendations'. For more on this feature, see [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/using-the-cpp-core-guidelines-checkers).

In [C++ Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) the specific recommendation the checker is using here is: [ES.103: Don't overflow](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Res-overflow).

The reason this only happens in x64 is because `size_t` is 64-bits while `int` is 32-bits. In x86, both `int` and `size_t` are 32-bits.

The `std::string` operator[] takes a `size_t`. The cleanest simplest fix here is:

```
for (size_t j= 0; j <10; j++)
```

You could also address this by explicitly promoting the `int` to `size_t` before the addition takes place:

```
if (mystring[size_t(j) + 1] == 'w') {
```

You could also ignore the warning by adding:

```
#pragma warning(disable : 26451)
```

Or you could disable the C++ Core Guidelines Checker.

Comment: Understood. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

This is how the `std::string` `[] operator` defined. It takes std::size_t.

```
char& operator[] (size_t pos);
const char& operator[] (size_t pos) const;
```

That's where the casting is taking place: int -> size_t.

https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/fixed-width-integers-and-size-t/

edit: See Chuck Walbourn answer

Answer (score 1):

> It seems to be related to Usual arithmetic conversions, such that, if the operands are of different types, a conversion is applied to one of them before calculation. But if they are equal, that still happens?

Your conclusion is incorrect.

VS thinks that `j + 1` has the potential to overflow. It recommends that you perform the arithmetic operation, `+`, on a wider integral type to reduce the chances of overflow. Note that `static_cast<std::size_t>(j) + 1` could, in theory, still overflow but VS does not care about that.

You don't get the warning in x86 mode since the size of `std::size_t` and `int` are same on that platform.